# How to switch view by locale in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'd like to use different views for different locale in Laravel instead of translate phrase by phrase.

Is there some mechanism or package that allows to do it?

Otherwhise how could I write my views and controllers such that it would be done cleanly and relaiably?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way might be to create a custom view loader helper method as a wrapper around the existing one.

```
function lcView($view, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
{
    return view($view.'.'.config('app.locale'), $data, $mergeData);
}
```

Then you call that one instead:

```
// in some controller method
return view('index', $someData); // old way
return lcView('index', $someData); // new way
```

And also name your files

```
index.en.blade.php
index.es.blade.php
index.sv.blade.php
```

Haven't tested it and I'm sure there might be some smarter way, but it should work and it's quite readable and understandable. :)

Comment: where does I put the lcView to make it global? No way to change the original view function in some way? Maybe I will use this method with some fallback mechanism if locale is not set or localized view is not found

Comment: That's up to you, but I usually create an `app/helpers.php` for general helpers, then add it in my composer.json autoload hash (`"files": ["app/helpers.php"]` I think is the syntax).